# How to make a certain number of arrays on java based on a user input

Tags: java, arrays

So in java: a user is prompted to input a number ("How many arrays?"), they input a number, and the number is stored in a variable... let's call it `n`.

I want to create n many two-dimensional arrays with size [n][n].

This code doesn't work but conceptually conveys my idea:

```
*User inputs "n"*

for (int counter = 0; counter < n; counter ++) {        
double D(counter)[][] = new double[n][n]    
    }
```

This sets the dimensions [n][n] appropriately, however the naming scheme clearly doesn't work.

I'm looking for a bunch of arrays:

```
double D0[][] =  
double D1[][] =  
double D2[][] =  
double D3[][] =  
...  
double Dn[][] =
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us why you need array of arrays first? Because there might be simpler ways to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for generating X arrays with 2dim-Length of X each:

```
private List<double[][]> generateArrayListWithNElements(int n) {
    List<double[][]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int counter=0; counter<n; counter++) {        
        arrayList.add(new double[n][n]); 
    }

    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be what I need, thanks :). What would be the syntax for then accessing each array in this list later? I.E I wanted to add two of the arrays from the list generated. EDIT: Actually I can probably watch a few videos on Array Lists and stop wasting your guys's time. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Lists are sortable and so also 2dim arrays or xdim arrays can be sort the right way to all values or only 1,2-X dimension with only few lines of code. you´re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> I then want to create n many 2 dimensional arrays with size [n][n]

It is as simple as this, but you may  want to tell us why you need this for. Perhaps there are better ways than creating an array of 2D arrays to solve your current problem. What you explicitly asked for is actually a 3D array.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = scn.nextInt();
double[][][] cube = new double[size][size][size];
```

Comment: i guess he´s trying to generate X arrays with X as size - not just createing a normal array with X elements

Comment: Hmm, he actually wants `n` number of 2D array of size `[n][n]`. That will be 3D array actually. It's odd for a beginner to ask for 3D array.

Comment: after edit this is a simple way to get the right result. but handling the right way with 3d-arrays can be complicated so maybe think about a list. @NowThatsDamp

Comment: You asked what I need it for: Later in the program, the user will fill in the values of the arrays (Not directly, through prompts that will direct the user input to the appropriate "Cell") (Is that proper terminology? I.E. Cell [1][2], cell [0][3], ect... Please correct my vocabulary if it is wrong) I will then take the determinate of each array (D0, D1, D2... Dn) and divide them in a way that solves a system of equations.

Comment: List of 2D array is definitely better than 3D array in most scenarios. But until he tells us what he need this data structure for, that will be what he explicitly asked for..